# Replace HTTP request

Tags: replace, firefox-addon, httprequest, xpcom

I need to redirect http request as part of a filter addon.
I am using an `nsIObserverService` which provides me with subject, topic, and data.
I know how to cancel the request but I need to replace the request with a URL to a block page.
I know how to redirect the window contents with `window.content.document.location.replace` but that kills all subsequent requests.
I only want to replace at the request level.
Please advise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205672/modify-url-before-loading-page-in-firefox/5207141#5207141

Answer (score 0):

on server that is processing your request try sending 301 response

for example an php redirect is like this

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://www.example.com');
exit();
```

Comment: oops ... I forgot to mention I have to do this in javascript.

Comment: well there in javascript in order to not to kill all subsequent request the only way is to have this redirect be the last of all requests, i don't think there is any other way